# Writing dynamic conditional statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a multistep form where a value (or multiples) of a form field determine whether a subsequent step is shown.

For example, the data I am receiving looks like:

```
{
    cardConditional:
        lessThan: 75
        show: true
        when: "fieldKeyHere"
    ...
}
```

This is basically telling me, if the `when` is `lessThan` 75 show the step. it can return `greaterThan` or `eq` as well which i've accounted for in the code below. My question is how can i take that information and construct a function to return true or false depending on that? I guess im stuck on how to string together that conditional with the string from `getMathSymbol`.

Here's what i have so far:

```
const checkStepConditional = (step) => {
    const getMathSymbol = () => {
      if (step.cardConditional.eq) return "===";
      else if (step.cardConditional.lessThan) return "<";
      else if (step.cardConditional.greaterThan) return ">";
    };

    if (step.cardConditional) {
      const conditionalFieldKey = step.cardConditional.when;
      return form.values[conditionalFieldKey]  <-- stuck here
    } else {
      return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Will you always have one of the properties `eq`, `lessThan` and `greaterThan` on a `cardCditional` step.

Comment: @NickParsons yes i would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object keyed by the conditions which each implements the method necessary for the comparison, and use an [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on the conditions that exist in your `cardConditional` object to check of all conditions match.

```js
const checkStepConditional = (form, step) => {
  const checkIf = {
    eq: (a, b) => a === b,
    lessThan: (a, b) => a < b,
    greaterThan: (a, b) => a > b,
  }

  if (step.cardConditional) {
    const cardCond = step.cardConditional;
    const field = form.values[cardCond.when];
    const conditions = Object.keys(checkIf).filter(k => k in cardCond);
    return conditions.every(condition => checkIf[condition](field, cardCond[condition]))
      ? cardCond.show
      : !cardCond.show
  }
};

const
  card = { cardConditional: { lessThan: 75, show: true, when: "fieldKeyHere", } },
  form = { values: { "fieldKeyHere": 60 } };
  console.log(checkStepConditional(form, card)); 
  // 60 < 75 ? show: true

const
  card1 = { cardConditional: { lessThan: 75, greaterThan: 60, show: true, when: "fieldKeyHere", } },
  form1 = { values: { "fieldKeyHere": 65 } };
  console.log(checkStepConditional(form1, card1)); 
  // 65 < 75 && 65 > 60 ? show: true

const
  card2 = { cardConditional: { lessThan: 75, greaterThan: 60, show: true, when: "fieldKeyHere", } },
  form2 = { values: { "fieldKeyHere": 55 } };
  console.log(checkStepConditional(form2, card2)); 
  // 55 < 75 && 55 > 60 ? show: false
```

Comment: Amazing - i love this approach. I was simply just going to eval() the combined string though thats 100% not the way to go. You nailed it - thanks!